# Identity component and rational point over algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-groups

For an algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (in general, an algebraically closed field with character $0$), let the identity component of G be denoted by $G_{0}$. I wonder whether the rational point of $G_0$ equals the identity component of $G$'s rational point, namely $G_0(\mathbb{C})=G(\mathbb{C})_0$, holds.

Here, the topology is defined with regard to the fact that rational point of an algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$ forms an Lie group over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Are you mixing algebraic and complex-topology constructions of an identity component of $G$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if, as **reuns** suggests, what you mean is the following:

> **Fact:** Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. Then, $(G^\circ)^\mathrm{an}=(G^\mathrm{an})^\circ$.

Here I am using $\circ$ to denote the connected component (of an algebraic group or a topological group) I am using $X^\text{an}$ to denote the analytification of a variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. equipping $X(\mathbb{C})$ with the usual structure of a complex analytic space).

The reason for this is simple. To show that $(G^\circ)^\text{an}$ is the connected component of $G^\text{an}$ we need to show that"

1. $(G^\circ)^\text{an}$ is connected.
2. $G^\text{an}/(G^\circ)^\text{an}$ is finite.

The first of these is a general property of the analytification functor in general (e.g. see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798432/connected-components-in-affine-algebraic-manifold/3798442#3798442) post) and for the second we note that $G/G^\circ$ is finite and eviently we have the following equality of sets

$$G^\text{an}/(G^\circ)^\text{an}=G(\mathbb{C})/G^\circ(\mathbb{C})=(G/G^\circ)(\mathbb{C})$$

from where the conclusion follows.